# Wine Launching Problems [Compiled Latest Version]

Tags: software-installation, wine, compiling

When I run `wine name.exe` it acts as if wine isn't installed (note this is a program that worked before just fine). When I run `winecfg` I get the config window. When I launch a program via "open with wine..." I get

```
KDEInit could not launch 'wine':
Could not open library '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkdeinit5_wine'.
Cannot load library /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkdeinit5_wine: (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkdeinit5_wine.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)
```

I've compiled wine 2.18 myself on Kubuntu 16.04 LTS.

Comment: My version isn't this new, but I remember reading that the commands to use it have changed in the latest revisions.  See if this helps: http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2017/01/install-wine-2-0-ubuntu-16-04-14-04-16-10/

Comment: I checked there and they didn't say anything about it changing, but that maybe my problem, let me search for a solution. Thanks.